# Probability Flipping coins consecutive heads

Tags: probability

A fair coin is tossed repeatedly. Let $t$ be the time at which we first see three consecutive
heads (thus flips number $t − 2, t − 1, t$ are all heads), and let $s$ be the time at which we
first see four consecutive heads. What is the probability that $s = t + 1$? And what is the
probability that $s = t + 9$?

Since $t$ is the first time we have 3 consecutive heads, the probability of $s = t+1$ is the probability of $t+1$ being heads which is $1/2$

For the second part;

t+1 must be tails = ($1/2$)

there must be at least one tails in (t+2, ..., t+5) = ($1-(\frac{1}{2
})^4$)

and t+6,.. t+9 must all be heads = $1/2^4$

therefore my final answer is $\frac{15}{2^9}$

Are my answers correct and if not where have i gone wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The first is right.

For the second, there must be a tail at $t+1$ **and** a tail at $t+5$, and then $4$ heads. We don't care what happens at $t+2,t+3,t+4$.

Comment: Ah, i missed that. So my final answer should be 1/2^6?

Comment: Yes, that's right.